# No library found for processing.io error error when running Processing code in raspberrypi

Tags: pi-3

I am trying to run a `Sketch` program using `Processing 4.0`. The code is from `FreeNove` `raspberrypi` kit.

I am getting this error

```
No library found for processing.io
No library found for processing.io
No library found for processing.io
Libraries must be installed in a folder named 'libraries' inside the sketchbook folder (see the Preferences window).
The package “processing.io” does not exist. You might be missing a library.
```

The code is snippt which seem to include `processing.io` is

```
/*****************************************************
 * Filename    : Sketch_09_1_1_Motor
 * Description : Control speed and direction of the motor
 * auther      : www.freenove.com
 * modification: 2016/08/22
 *****************************************************/
import processing.io.*;

int motorPin1 = 17;    //connect to the L293D
int motorPin2 = 27;
int enablePin = 22;
final int borderSize = 45;    //border size
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I’m late, however, responding just in case someone else has the same issue.

Seems that the Hardware I/O library isn’t enabled by default for your sketches in Processing V4.

The following resolved it for me – using Processing 4.0.1 Arm 32;

- Start Processing
- In the Processing UI, go to: Tools > Manage tools
- Click Tab: Libraries
- Filter: All
- Search for: Hardware I/O
- Click Install